# Rails console vs module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes (`data`)

```
sort_column = "Me.You.Them"
```

I need to sort the array by the `sort_column`.
When I do `data.sort_by { |h| h.dig(sort_column.split('.').map(&:to_s))}` in the rails console, I get the data returned sorted, but when I place the exact same method in my helper module, it returns nil.

Anyone knows why?

Here are my methods:

My helper file:

```
module DatatablesHelper
    def fetch_data(data, sort_column, sort_direction)
        if sort_column.present? 
            if sort_direction == "desc"
                sorted_leads = data.sort_by { |h| h.dig(sort_column.split('.').map(&:to_s))}
            else
                sorted_leads = data.sort_by { |h| -h.dig(sort_column.split('.').map(&:to_s))}
            end
        else
            sorted_results = data
        end
        return sorted_results
    end
end
```

My controller and action

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
    include DatatablesHelper
    def get_data
        data = [
            {},
            {}
        ] # Here imagine we have a large array of hashes returned from an api
        sort_column = params['order']["0"] # => "Me.You.Them"
        final = fetch_data(data, sort_column, "desc")
        render json: {
            recordsTotal: data.count,
            recordsFiltered: final.count,
            data: final
        }
    end
end
```

Comment: You should probably show the definition that's returning `nil`; it's exceedingly likely that that's where the issue lies.

Comment: @coreyward - added my controller and helper file methods. Hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: you are returning `sorted_results` but this only gets set when there is no `sort_column` present change `sorted_leads` to `sorted_results`

Comment: How embarrassing... :/ Thanks @engineersmnky

Comment: Why are you sorting the data in the method called `fetch_data` It looks like this method is doing to much. I would advise moving the logic related to sorting to a separate method.